# SwiftyJSON gets the file but I can't access it

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

So I'm trying to get the JSON file and it all seems to work fine when I print it to the console.

```
var dta:JSON = nil
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.vikinglogue.com/api/get_posts/")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
    if data != nil {
        dta = JSON(data: data!)
        println(dta)
    }

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.dta["count"].stringValue
    println(self.dta["count"].stringValue)
    return cell
}
```

Although, the "println(self.dta["count"].stringValue)" doesn't print out anything when it should be printing out a 12.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did `println(dta)` print out the value?

Comment: yes it did, i realized that i was spelling one of the JSON calls wrong